# CSS - Horizontal center on :after arrow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center horizontally the "arrow" :after on my  but I don't manage to do it...

My HTML

```
<div class="menu-top">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> <a href="">Avant</a>

                </td>
                <td class="active"> <a href="">jambon</a>

                </td>
                <td class="active"> <a href="">Historique des transferts</a>

                </td>
                <td> <a href="">Testeuh</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.menu-top {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.menu-top table {
    background: lightgrey;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-top table td a {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #3f4348;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.menu-top table td.active a:before {
    content:'';
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 25px;
    border-top: 16px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
}
```

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnfnnwc4/7/)

I tried with an other style [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnfnnwc4/8/), but I would like to have the first Style (with grey arrow and more bigger)

Can you Help me please :)

Thank you !

Comment: Well, it's a `::before` arrow, not an `::after` arrow

Comment: Don't use a table as a menu.

Comment: This is exactly the reason we ***don't use tables for layout***. Use divs etc instead - flexbox would even do this better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0 auto;
```

to this class:

```
.menu-top table td.active a:before
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this `right:0; left:0; margin:auto;` will work best in all browsers that supports `:before` no performance hit as well.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/rnfnnwc4/10/)

```
.menu-top table td.active a:before {
    content:'';
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 25px;
    border-top: 16px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;

    /* add these styles as well */

    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### CSS3 Solution (`calc()`)

With CSS3's `calc()` function we can position our arrow to `50%` minus `16px` (where `16px` is equal to half of the arrow's width).

```css
left: calc(50% - 16px);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnfnnwc4/11/).

### CSS2 Solution (`margin`)

Without CSS3's `calc()` function we can set the `left` property to `50%` and adjust the element to the left by `16px` using a negative `margin-left`.

```css
left: 50%;
margin-left: -16px;
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnfnnwc4/12/).

### Alternative CSS2 Solution (`left` and `right`)

As mentioned by Nick in comments, another way to achieve this is by setting both the `left` and `right` properties to `0`, and setting the `margin` to `auto`:

```css
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnfnnwc4/13/).

Comment: If it could be done without `calc()`, always use that alternative.

Comment: `left:0; right:0;margin:0 auto;` would be better if you ever decide to change the image

Comment: @HerrSerker care to explain why?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly `calc()` would probably use more performance of the browser. And of course there is http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: @Nick nice idea. I've added that into the answer.

Comment: the update with the `left:0; right:0; margin:auto;` works well, thanks James

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (3 new lines on your CSS). More [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-center-position-absolute-div/) about how to center an absolute element

```
.menu-top table td.active a:before {
    content:'';
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 25px;
    border-top: 16px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    width: 32px; // width of the arrow
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -16px; // half of width of the arrow
}
```

Comment: `width: 32px` is not necessary

Comment: the margin-left in px is never going to work (in the last line) as the length of the text in characters are very different. Try using `left: -20%;` & `margin-left: 40%;` in the last 2 lines. It pretty much centers the arrows, but not just there yet